# APLpy show markers normalized by a colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, aplpy

I am using APLpy to plot a fits file and want to overplot markers on that fits file at certain ra,dec values. I want the colours of the markers to be coded with another parameter, lets say a magnitude.

So what I do is I read the marker coordinates and the corresponding magnitudes from a textfile (positions.dat):

```
ra         = np.genfromtxt('positions.dat', dtype=float, comments='%', delimiter=';', missing_values='_', skip_header=1, usecols = (0))                                 
dec        = np.genfromtxt('positions.dat', dtype=float, comments='%', delimiter=';', missing_values='_', skip_header=1, usecols = (1))                                 
magnitude  = np.genfromtxt('positions.dat', dtype=float, comments='%', delimiter=';', missing_values='_', skip_header=1, usecols = (2))
```

I define a colormap and its normalization:

```
cmap1 = mpl.cm.YlOrBr                                                           
norm1 = mpl.colors.Normalize(10,20)
```

My magnitudes in the positions.dat file are all between 10 and 20 to test the code.

I tried to plot the markers as follows:

```
fits1.show_markers(ra,dec, cmap=cmap1, norm=norm1, edgecolor=magnitude, facecolor='none', marker='x', s= 4, linewidths=0.8)
```

When I do this, I always get the error:

```
ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional
```

The positions.dat file looks like that:

```
  ra    ;      dec     ;   magnitude
330.45  ;  -31.958333  ;      10.0
330.46  ;  -31.958333  ;      11.0
330.47  ;  -31.958333  ;      12.0
330.48  ;  -31.958333  ;      13.0
330.49  ;  -31.958333  ;      14.0
330.50  ;  -31.958333  ;      15.0
330.51  ;  -31.958333  ;      16.0
330.52  ;  -31.958333  ;      17.0
330.53  ;  -31.958333  ;      18.0
330.54  ;  -31.958333  ;      19.0
330.55  ;  -31.958333  ;      20.0
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767526/value-error-with-color-array-when-slicing-values-for-scatter-plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that matplotlib's scatter can't take values for `edgecolor` and `facecolor` that are not color arrays (that is, arrays of RGB values). The correct way to achieve what you are trying to do is to use scatter's `c` argument, so in this case:

```
fits1.show_markers(ra,dec, cmap=cmap1, norm=norm1,
                   c=magnitude, facecolor='none',
                   marker='x', s=4, linewidths=0.8)
```