# aplpy show_polygons() with colorised faces

Tags: python, matplotlib, aplpy

I've got some polygons I'd like to plot in Right Ascension/Declination space with APLpy, with the polygons colored by another 1D list, but I can't get `show_polygons()` to work.

I tried to adapt the answer from [APLpy show markers normalized by a colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902162/aplpy-show-markers-normalized-by-a-colormap) , but when I run it, `show_polygons()` doesn't understand the kwargs `cmap`, `norm`, or `c` the same way `show_markers()` does.

My adapted, standalone script:

```
import aplpy, numpy
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors

polygons = [array([[ 46.33681474,  34.75536787],
   [ 45.04752709,  35.37650737],
   [ 44.63035494,  34.73768723],
   [ 46.33681474,  34.75536787]]), array([[ 46.45913142,  34.69050337],
   [ 45.04717721,  35.37189917],
   [ 44.6205633 ,  34.72362768],
   [ 46.45913142,  34.69050337]]), array([[ 46.52741447,  34.64997822],
   [ 45.04457814,  35.36619781],
   [ 44.60486296,  34.70107236],
   [ 46.52741447,  34.64997822]])]
zvalues = [  1.02018589e-10,   9.38471764e-12,   2.15806865e-11]

cmap1 = cm.YlOrBr
norm1 = colors.Normalize( numpy.min(zvalues), numpy.max(zvalues) )
fig   = aplpy.FITSFigure( numpy.zeros( (10,10) ) )
fig.show_polygons( polygons, cmap=cmap1, norm=norm1, c=zvalues, facecolor='none' )
plt.save( fname='plot.png' )
```

Running this causes `show_polygons()` to raise different AttributeErrors:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property cmap
AttributeError: Unknown property norm
AttributeError: Unknown property c
```

My versions of things:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
$ python
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print(matplotlib.__version__)
1.5.1
>>> import aplpy
>>> print(aplpy.__version__)
1.1.1
```

How can I get `show_polygons()` to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the polygon coordinates you're trying to plot don't match with the pixel array you're plotting - although I assume that's not a problem for a real fits figure you're plotting. So you should change your code to something like this instead:

```
# fixed so that the polygons fall inside the image
fig = aplpy.FITSFigure(numpy.zeros((50,50)))
# zoom in on the coord values of the polygons
fig.recenter(45.5, 35, 1.5)
```

Now, actually answering the question: different methods of `aplpy.FITSFigure` pass keyword arguments to different `matplotib` routines - so you shouldn't expect `show_polygons` and `show_markers` to behave in the same way. In fact, their docstrings state that `show_poligons` passes its `kwargs` to a `PatchCollection` class, while `show_markers` would send them along to `plt.scatter`. That's why the attribute errors keep happening.

So, how to color the patches by a 1d color list then? As far as I know, there's no one-liner solution, but you can loop over the polygons and color them individually:

```
for p, c in zip(polygons, zvalues):
        fig.show_polygons([p], facecolor=cmap1(norm1(c)),
                          edgecolor='none', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following figure for me:

[image: those elusive polygons]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that seems to partially work.  It looks like all coordinates are in the pixel's cartesian system (due to the numpy.zeros())?  I needed it where the polygon corner coordinates are spherical (RA,Dec) coordinates , not cartesian (x,y).

Comment: You need to pass a valid HDU or a path to a fits file to `aplpy.FITSFigure` for it to plot in sky coordinates. This isn't what your original post shows, as you only give it a pixel array.

Comment: I was using `zeros()` because of another example I found, without knowing all of its consequences.  I don't have a fits file to start with.  I think `FITSFigure` can accept an `astropy.wcs.WCS()` object instead of `zeros()`, but I can't figure out how to get one setup for J2000 RA/Dec.  Maybe thats a topic for a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: @nk it should be relatively straightforward to make a minimal header and generate a wcs object with `astropy` from it. But yes, it seems a bit beyond your original question.